# Registration form can't write data into a database

Tags: php, mysql

I watched a tutorial on how to make a registration form with PHP and MySQL, every time I try error message show ""User could not be added to the database". Here is my code:

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    $username = "";
    $email    = "";
    $password = "";

    $_SESSION['message']='';



    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');



    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm-password']){
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
           mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if($db->query($query) === true){
          $_SESSION['message']="Registration succesful! Added $username to the datebase!";
          header("location: welcome.php");
        }
        else {
          $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";
        }
      }
      else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Password did not match!";
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Add a check for what exact error happens and you’ll have a lot better idea what’s going on. The database won’t just say yes or no, it’ll tell you what went wrong and you’re not checking that

Comment: I today start with PHP/MySQL so I dont understand how to see error list

Comment: SQL INJECTION ALERT (use PDO! Or at least switch to prepared statements!)

Comment: I'm glad you put some thought into SQL injection with input escaping, but please be aware that it's not 100% effective and a clever attacker may yet find a way to send little Bobby Tables around for a visit.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You're executing your query twice. Remove this `mysqli_query($db, $query);` from above and you can check  that if statement just writing `if($db->query($query))`

Comment: Now browser leave this error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: You accepted the answer, ask that guy for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try putting `$db->error` in your else statement and see what it says.. If there is error or exception

```
 if($db->query($query) === true){
          $_SESSION['message']="Registration succesful! Added $username to the datebase!";
          header("location: welcome.php");
        }
        else {
            echo $db->error; 
            die();

          $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";
        }
```

Comment: Now i have this error "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Answer (score 1):

make your id `AUTO_INCREMENT` starting from 1 for every table